# How to setup my .htaccess file to find my index.html?

Tags: .htaccess

I had a wordpress installation on my website : www.kud-ivancice.hr, I deleted the files, and droped the tables, and then copied my new website on the server. I edited my .htaccess, deleted the wordpress code and now it states : DirectoryIndex index.html, but when i try to open the page, it doesn't work. This is the first time I'm doing this, and am feeling quite lost. Any tips?

Comment: Doesn't work? As in it doesn't show the page? Or it throws an error?

Comment: when i type my domain in the browser it sends me to : http://kud-ivancice.hr/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/